# rsync here or superuser?

Tags: discussion

I am on my way to a Marshall badge on SO so I figure I should know but I still can't figure out whether rsync belongs here or to Superuser. There are 1,654 on SO, 866 on SU, 1,666 here.

Also, why was this refused as "It does not meet our quality standards" until I wrote this paragraph?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When considering such migrations do consider:

- Flagging to close crap for being crap (at the moment you're still under the line for SO) earns you flag-rep for your Marshal hunt. Once you cross 3K though, they're turned to close votes and don't count for flag-rep.
- If the question is just about how to use [rsync](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/rsync), SU or Unix & Linux are better homes. U&L is good if they mention a specific distro in the question or tags.
- Dev-server and home-server usage are specifically off-topic here.
- When coming from SO, assume it's a dev-server unless it is clear it isn't for some reason. Dev-server questions go to SU (or U&L).

The FAQ's admonition about '*in a professional capacity*' means different things to different people and has shifted a bit over time. In recent months, this appears to be a good working definition:

> On servers or networking equipment, in the workplace itself, handling or intending to handle production/integration tasks, managed by administrators specifically authorized to do this kind of work.

Which doesn't cover the storage questions we get, but it's good enough for this task.

Answer (score 7):

This depends upon the context of the question. Our [**FAQ**](https://serverfault.com/faq#questions) clearly states "*Server Fault is for system administrators and desktop support professionals, people who manage or maintain computers in a professional capacity.*".

If the question meets those criteria then it has a home on SF.

Having had a look at questions tagged [rsync](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/rsync) on SO please remember the mantra 'Don't migrate crap'.

Regarding the question about quality standards - The [algorithm isn't published](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards).

Comment: Sorry that FAQ is *not* clear. It's very hard to decide whether an rsync comamnd sought is in "professional capacity" or just from a desktop to a home server.

Comment: No, the [faq] is clear - the context of the question isn't. If **you** can't decide then **you** should leave it.

Comment: OK take http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110404/rsync-changed-files-on-server this. Where?

Comment: Nowhere, not without getting further clarification from the OP about the question background. There's insufficient context to understand where it belongs so it should be closed where it is if its OT where it is. And one of the golden rules of migrations is "Don't migrate crap" - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82941/please-dont-migrate-low-quality-questions-to-other-sites/82986#82986

Comment: That looks like a developer working with a dev server but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I use rsync both at home and at work. If I had a question in relation to the former it would belong on SU, whereas for the latter it's proper SF material. Pretty simple really. Why would you image it belongs on only one or the other?