# What goes into the decision of posting something on SF or on another more specific stackexchange?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

When I need to ask a Linux related question, I normally look at the activity on the related unix.se and sf tags to decide where to post it.

I read in [a previous question](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/838/cross-posting-to-unix-stackexchange-com) that cross-posting might be okay if the site is beta (is unix.se still beta?)

Comment: The Beta distinction no longer applies, do not cross post please.

Answer (score 1):

The context of the question is important. If you substitute [your-tag](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/your-tag) for [rsync](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/rsync) in [this question](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/2258/9517) and it's answers then you should get a feel for what goes where. There is though considerable overlap.

[Unix and Linux](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3924/unix-linux) was launched from beta some time ago.

Comment: +1 There's a lot of overlap. If the question is more geared to your job's responsibilities I'd go [SF], otherwise [Unix.SE] is commonly just as appropriate. Mods can migrate between either anyway, should you post in the *wrong* site.

Comment: What makes it the "wrong" site? I.e., in what cases would a mod migrate from "Unix and Linux" to "Serverfault" and vice versa?

Comment: There is no definitive answer to this. Some questions are clearly off topic - home server on SF for example but many fall into the overlap most scripting questions for example. [::gallic shrug::](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/je_ne_sais_quoi)

Comment: [unix.SE] tends to be more hobbyist and single computer type questions. They rarely migrate to [SF] but do when it clearly involves administering many computers in a professional environment. I personally like to move non-SF questions to [unix.SE] if the Question involves any flavor of *nix and doesn't fit in the confines of [SF] (home, single computer, non-professional, non System Administrator related). [SU] is already a dumping ground where Question go to die (or get inane answers; nearly as bad).